# Passing $scope through AJAX, but only few variables inserted

Tags: angularjs, ajax

I am trying to pass a variable through AJAX to an API. Here is the angular controller:

```
$scope.register = function() {
    _.each($scope.photos, function(images) {
        $upload.upload({
            url: '/api/indorelawan/timaksibaik/register/upload-images',
            method: 'POST',
            data: {},
            file: images
        })
        .success(function(data) {
            $scope.team.photos.push(data.result.path);
        })
    });
    $http({
        method  : 'POST',
        url     : '/api/indorelawan/timaksibaik/register',
        data    : $.param($scope.team),
        headers : { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
    })
    .success(function(data) {
        if (!data.success) {
            ...
        }
        else {
            ...
        }
    });
}
```

I tried console.log the $scope.team.photos before it calls the /register API. It displays the data perfectly. But when /register API is runned, the $scope.team.photos is not included. Here is the API:

```
/*Register Tim Aksi Baik*/
apiRouter.post('/timaksibaik/register', function(req, res) {
    // TODO: Create new value to access general statistics data, e.g.: response time.
    console.log(req.body);
    var team = new GoodActionTeam();

  _.each(req.body, function(v, k) {
      team[k] = v;
  });

  team.created = new Date();

    team.save(function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
                res.status(500).json({
                success: false,
                message: "Gagal menyimpan data organisasi baru.",
                system_error: "Error while saving organization data: " + err.message
            });
        }
        else {
            res.status(200).json({
                success: true,
                message: "Organisasi Berhasil Dibuat",
                result: data
            });
        }
    });
});
```

The output of the req.body is only:

> { logo: '/uploads/user_avatar/register/2018-1-14_18:18:3.png',
>     name: 'ererr',
>     url_string: 'ererr',
>     description: 'dfdfd',
>     focuses: [ '549789127e6a6e2c691a1fc0', '549789127e6a6e2c691a1fc0' ] }

It looks like the $scope.team.photos is not included when the data is passed to the API. What went wrong?

Comment: seems like `$upload.upload()` is asynchronous (and also executed in a loop), so it's possible that you need to resolve all of those promises with `$q.all()` and _then_ run your `$http.post` (_i.e. "chaining"_)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `$upload.upload()` is async and by the time you make a post with `$scope.team` there is no guarantee that all the upload success callbacks have been completed